# Laravel - Script won't function unless browser refreshed or page directly visited

Tags: jquery, laravel

The script will only run on my page if it is refreshed. The strange thing is, if I look in the console there are no errors and it looks like it is actually running. Below is my app.blade.php file and my view file. If I refresh the page, it runs just fine, but if I visit from another page it won't load correctly. Below are simplified versions of my code. The first is the app.blade.php and the second the view file. The code works just fine if the screen is refereshed or the page is directly visited.

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html @php language_attributes() @endphp class="show-transition-cover">

@include('partials.head')

<body @php body_class() @endphp>

    @php do_action('get_header') @endphp
    @include('partials.header')

    <div id="wrapper" class="page-{!! $get_slugs['templateSlug'] !!} page-type-{!! $get_slugs['postType'] !!}" role="document">
      <main id="content" role="document" router-wrapper>

        @yield('content')
      </main>
      @php do_action('get_footer') @endphp
    </div>

    @include('partials.footer')

    <div class="transition-cover">
      <div class="transition-cover-content">
        <div class="brand-container" >
          <div class="site-header__left-container"></div>
          <div class="site-header__brand-container">
            <div class="brand hidden" >
              <div class="svg-container" >
                @php include App\svg_path('logo.svg') @endphp
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="site-header__right-container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="transition-cover-phrase">
          <div class="container w-75">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="h1 transition-cover-title">
                <div class="text"></div>

              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    @php wp_footer() @endphp


          @yield('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my view file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div router-view="floorPlansRouter" class="page-{!! $get_slugs['templateSlug'] !!} page-type-{!! $get_slugs['postType'] !!}" data-cover-phrase="FLOOR PLANS">

<section class="newfloorplans">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flooplanList filter-button-group">
            <ul>
            <li><span class="is-checked" data-filter="all">All Plans</span> /</li>
            <li><span data-filter="studio">Studio</span> /</li>
            <li><span data-filter="onebed"><sup class="number">1</sup> Bedroom</span> /</li>
            <li><span data-filter="onebedden"><sup class="number">1</sup> Bedroom + Den</span> /</li>
            <li><span data-filter="twobed"><sup class="number">2</sup> Bedroom</span> /</li>
            <li><span data-filter="townhouse">Townhouse</span> /</li>
            <li><span class="sitelink">Sitemap</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="hr container "></div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="grid">

            @include('floorplans.studio')
            @include('floorplans.onebed')
            @include('floorplans.onebedden')
            @include('floorplans.twobed')
            @include('floorplans.townhome')
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- IFRAME -->
        <div router-view="floorPlansRouter" class="page-{!! $get_slugs['templateSlug'] !!} page-type-{!! $get_slugs['postType'] !!}" data-cover-phrase="FLOOR PLANS">
          <a id="sitemap"></a>
            <section class="page-section type-sightmap-embed">
                <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="embed-container" src="https://sightmap.com/embed/{{ get_field('embed_id') }}"></iframe>
            </section>

        </div>
        <!-- IFRAME -->
    </div>
</section>

    @include('partials.section_instagram_feed')
    @include('partials.section_contact_cta')

</div>

@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
alert( "welcome now" );
        $('.flooplanList ul li span').not('.sitelink').click(function(){
                    $('.flooplanList ul li span').each(function(index, el) {
                        $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
                    });
            $(this).toggleClass("is-checked");  // toggle active on current

            if ( $(this).data("filter") == "all" )  {
                $(".element-item").each(function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(200);
                });
            }
            else {
                filter();  // filter elements
            }


        });


        var filter = function() {
          // array of classes that items need to have
          var classes = $(".flooplanList ul li span.is-checked")
              .map(function() {
                return $(this).data("filter");
              })
              .toArray();

              console.log(classes)

          $(".element-item").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            // it should show if it has all classes as the settings say
            var show = classes.every(function(aClass) {
              return $this.hasClass(aClass);  // class is a reserved word
            });

            console.log(show)
            // toggle appropriately
            if(show) {
              $this.fadeIn(200);
            }
            else {
              $this.fadeOut(200);
            }
          });
        };

        // INLINED
        // MORE INFO
        $('.flplink span.button').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $(".element-item").each(function() {
                    var activeones = $(this).find('.moreinfo.is-active');
                    activeones.removeClass('is-active');
            });

            var moreinfo = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.moreinfo');
            moreinfo.insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().parent())
            moreinfo.toggleClass('is-active');
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('is-active');



            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('html,body').on('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function() {
                   $('html,body').stop();
                 });
                 $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: moreinfo.offset().top - 100
                 }, 500);
               }, 500);



        });

        $('.moreinfo .close').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var moreinfo = $(this).parent().parent();
                moreinfo.removeClass('is-active');
                var iback = moreinfo.parent().find('.element-item.is-active');
                moreinfo.appendTo(iback);





                setTimeout(function() {
                     $('html,body').on('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function() {
                       $('html,body').stop();
                     });
                     $('html,body').animate({
                       scrollTop: iback.offset().top - 200
                     }, 500);

                     $(".element-item").each(function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('is-active');
                     });

                   }, 500);


        });


        $('.flooplanList ul li span.sitelink').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#sitemap').offset().top - 200
            }, 500);
        });


    });
</script>@endsection
```

Comment: Probably not it, but this just feels like a caching issue to me. Have you tried clearing the browser and/or laravel caches?

Comment: I have. I am testing in incognito and clearing the cache etc. How would I clear the laravel cache? But seems weird that is works once I refreshed the browser.

Comment: `php artisan | grep clear` for all the clear commands. Like, `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: @ourmandave Thank you - It didn't work however.

Comment: There are lots of things happening in this code that we can't see the results of here: views being included, Wordpress functions running, etc. Try removing or commenting out big chunks of code until you can get the script working (or at least the `alert()` on the first line inside the script tags), then add back a few lines at a time until it breaks again. That should help you narrow down the search. Good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve